# How to connect Haxe project with Nape

Tags: ubuntu, haxe, nape

I have a src folder, containing a Main.hx & compile.hxml.
I run the command `sudo haxelib install nape`, which reported it ended successfully installing Nape 2.0.5.

In the Main.hx I posted the code from [this page](http://napephys.com/samples.html#haxe-BasicSimulation), and then I run `haxe compil.hxml`
which gave me the error:
`characters 0-22 : Class not found : nape.geom.Vec2`.
I can conclude haxe doesn't 'see' Nape.

Sidenote: I use ubuntu 12.10.

How do I use the library in my code?

Answer (score 2):

What does your .hxml look like?

you should have a line like '-lib nape' to link with the nape library.

On a different side note: Why are you running haxelib with sudo? It should not be necessary.

Comment: Not only should `sudo` not be necessary, but it may actually have unexpected results. It maybe install in a different location, or have the wrong permissions etc.

Comment: You define lib location by yourself, so nothing unexpected here.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using openfl and got this same error then in project.xml

add this (as XML tag like the openfl one )

```
 <haxelib name="nape" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this library, but I know it was written in pre-macro times and used a special pre-processor for haxe, called caxe. Looking at github sources of the library I don't see much .hx files, mostly .cx. For example, there is `nape/geom/Vec2.cx`, but no `nape/geom/Vec2.hx`.

So, my assumption is the library should be precompiled first, probably by means of Makefile it comes packed with, however I wasn't able to find any documentation on the issue.

Comment: I don't expect anyone to be using the actual source code unless they're actively modifying it. The library is on haxelib with the already preprocessed source in .hx format.